# How does Go preempt goroutines in windows?

Tags: multithreading, go, winapi, goroutine, preemption

I read that goroutines are now preemptible. The preemption is done via a `sysmon` goroutine that sends stop signals to goroutines which have used up their time slice. On posix systems, I believe this is done through `pthread_kill`. My question is: how does this work in windows since windows doesn't support thread signaling? I had assumed that the go runtime may have been using a posix thread library like `pthreads4w`, however I just saw that even in `pthreads4w`, `pthread_kill` doesn't support sending signals.

Comment: Go is open source. You should be able to read the source and find out how it works.

Comment: This depends on the compiler used.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in [`runtime/preempt.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/preempt.go) give an overview of how preemption works in the runtime. Specifically to do with *asynchronous* preemption:

> Preemption at asynchronous safe-points is implemented by suspending the thread using an OS mechanism (e.g., signals) and inspecting its state to determine if the goroutine was at an asynchronous safe-point.

So how does async preemption work on windows? As mentioned in the original [proposal](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/24543-non-cooperative-preemption.md) for non-cooperative preemption of goroutines:

> #### Other considerations
>
> ... signaled preemption is quite easy to support in Windows because it provides `SuspendThread` and `GetThreadContext` ...

The Windows [`SuspendThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-suspendthread) function can be used to suspend a thread by its handle, and [`GetThreadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadcontext) can be used to get the processor state of the thread. The specific usages of these functions are implemented in [`runtime/os_windows.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/os_windows.go)